# How to add recursive directory to batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I have the following batch file:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d [*]*'
) do for /f "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in (
  "%%F"
) do for /f "tokens=*" %%C in ("%%B") do ren "%%F" "%%C"
```

I want launch it in the root directory and have it go through all directories and subdirectories performing the actions.

I tried adding /D and /r to the 'for' lines, but it doesn't appear to be working.

Do I need add something like...

for /D /r do

under the @echo off ?

Comment: What is the third `for` command for? to skip files that match `[*]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *either* `dir` *or* `for` to get all the files, don't mix it up.
When using `dir /S` for recursive enumeration, regard that full paths are output rather than pure file names only.
This should do it:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /s /b /a-d [*]*'
) do for /f "tokens=2* delims=]" %%B in (
  "%%~nxF"
) do for /f "tokens=*" %%C in ("%%B") do ren "%%~F" "%%C"
```

So I just changed the following in your original code:

- added `/s` to `dir` (returns full paths then);
- improved second `for` options (you never used the first token `%%A`, so why extract it then?);
- replaced set `%%F` of second `for` by `%%~nxF` to just parse the file name (type `for /?` for details concerning substitution modifiers such as `~n`, `~x`);
- replaced source argument "`%%F`" of `ren` command by "`%%~F`" to not fall into double-double-quote problems (the `~` modifier removes potential double-quotes);

Comment: I tried both methods, and they both worked quite well.

Comment: I selected yours as the answer because of the detail you added explaining the various parts.  That was very helpful to me, and I know others will find it helpful as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using "dir" for the enumeration of files, so add "/s" to the DIR command.

I might refactor what you have like this to make it easier to manage.
This also does recursion.

```
call :TOP .
goto :EOF

:TOP
    setlocal
    cd "%~f1"
    for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d [*]*') do call :SubRoutine "%%F"

    for /D %%x in (*) do call :TOP "%%x"  || (echo FAILED2 "%%x" && exit /b 2)
    goto :EOF

:SubRoutine
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=]" %%A in ("%~1") do call :SubRoutine2  "%~1" "%%A" "%%B" 
    goto :EOF

:SubRoutine2
    for /f "tokens=*" %%C in ("%~3") do ren "%~1" "%%C"
    goto :EOF
```

Comment: I like the approach to this one as it's easier for me to read and understand.